# Prisma update with relation in WHERE property

Tags: sql, prisma

Given these schemas:

```
model awayinfo {
PlayerID   Int        @id
IsAway     Boolean
playerinfo playerinfo @relation(fields: [PlayerID], references: [ID])
}
    
model playerinfo {
name       String    @db.VarChar(15)
ID         Int       @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
awayinfo   awayinfo?
}
```

**How would I create a prisma SQL update for the awayinfo table if the only identifier I have would be the Name of a player and not the ID?**

what I tried:

I try to pass something into the WHERE part as seen below:

```
const result = await prisma.awayinfo.update({
    where: {
      PlayerID: {
        name: name
      }
  },
    data: {
      IsAway: true,
    }
  });
```

but it always gives me the Error:

```
Invalid `prisma.awayinfo.update()` invocation: 

Argument PlayerID: Got invalid value
{
  name: 'Dummy'

}
on prisma.updateOneawayinfo. Provided Json, expected Int.
```

I got pretty desperate and even tried wonky selects like this one

```
 const result = await prisma.awayinfo.update({
    where: {
      PlayerID: {
      playerinfo: {
        Where: {
        name: name
      },
      select: {ID: true},
    }}
  }, .....
```

but obviously  this would not work aswell.
I wonder what I am missing here and I cannot find any example of a condition within the WHERE clause in the prisma documentation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two issues here, the first is in your Prisma schema/data model and the second is in your query.

#### Making `name` unique

Firstly, if you want to uniquely identify a record in the `playerinfo` table with *just* the `name` property, this property *must* be `unique`. Otherwise, it's not possible for your database (and Prisma) to know *which* player info record to update in case there are multiple records with the same `name` property.

Update your schema accordingly:

```
model playerinfo {
  name     String    @unique @db.VarChar(15)
  ID       Int       @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  awayinfo awayinfo?
}
```

#### Rewriting the update query

Since the `where` condition in your update references a property `playerinfo` model, that is where you should begin your query. Here's what it looks like:

```js
const data = await prisma.playerinfo.update({
    where: {
        name: name
    }, 
    data: {
        awayinfo: {
            update: {
                IsAway: true
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This answer is very detailed and solved the problem completly. I figured the unique part out myself but thank you again for pointing that out aswell!

Comment: Welcome! Happy to help :D

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative:**  call `updateMany` instead of `update`

In prisma `update` function expects a where condition that uniquely identifies a single record.

Hence either fetch records using `updateMany` or put name unique.

Although you cannot select or include anything with `updateMany`.

Comment: i feel like this is a good alternative as well if we want to keep the `prisma.awayInfo.update` instead of the `prisma.playerInfo.update` but might be misleading when reading the code and seing `updateMany` when in fact we only mean to update one row